# I'm getting an error while deploying Node.Js app with mongoDB on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are trying to deploy mongoDB with Node.js on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk but its giving an error which looks completely out of this planet. Please help!

[Instance: i-28bfc6e4] **Command failed on instance**. Return **code: 127 Output**: (TRUNCATED)...riorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper Package mongo-10gen-server-2.4.14-mongodb_1.x86_64 **is obsoleted by mongodb-org-serve**r-2.6.10-1.x86_64 which is already installed Nothing to do /etc/init.d/mongos.sh: line 1: /usr/bin/mongos: **No such file or directory**. Hook **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/98_newrelic_sysmond.sh** failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Answer (score 0):

if using the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983073/894487) then this got me going:

`01_enable_rootaccess:
     command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
   02_install_mongo:
-    command: yum install -y mongo-10gen-server
+    command: yum install -y mongo-10gen-server mongodb-org-mongos
     ignoreErrors: true
   03_turn_mongod_off:
     command: sudo chkconfig mongod off`