# MongoDB linked to EC2/Elastic beantalk

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying for days to deploy MongoDB to my EC2 instance/Elastic Beanstalk. I have found this question : [Mongos Install/Setup in Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961046/mongos-install-setup-in-elastic-beanstalk)

which seems to answer my problem however I dont understand where to place a .ebextensions" and "aws.config" file. I read that it said in my webapps folder.. Does that mean in my war file itself? or in the actual instance?

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: To be clear, you want to run MongoDB on the same EC2 instances that are created and managed by ElasticBeanstalk as part of your application deployment? That's a really bad idea. If you are having this much trouble figuring out how to (and where to) setup your MongoDB server, you should probably just use the mlab.com service instead.

Comment: Can you actually use mLab as part of elastic beantalk though? like if i deploy my server side web app is it possible for the values from mlab to connect to that web app? @MarkB

Comment: Sure, you can have your server connect to anything accessible on the internet, as well as anything accessible within AWS. Elastic Beanstalk wouldn't be very useful if your app server could never connect to anything outside Elastic Beanstalk. Note that your question about connecting mlab to Elastic Beanstalk is probably part of your confusion, a database doesn't "connect to" an app server, it goes the other direction. The app server connects to the database.